# SQL in python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in genre

Tags: python, sqlite

When I run the code it says type error in line where "genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]", I dont know what is happening. It makes sense to me but I dont see where is wrong. It starts doing the list but stops in a part. I tried changin the order but it doesnt makes sense, I saw the solution that is basically the same but different names and... it works but doesnt understand why mine doesnt

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('trackdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.executescript('''

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Artist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Album;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Track;
CREATE TABLE Artist (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Album (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    artist_id  INTEGER,
    title   TEXT UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Track (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    album_id  INTEGER,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    len INTEGER, rating INTEGER, count INTEGER
);
''')


fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'Library.xml'

# <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
# <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
# <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            found = True
    return None

stuff = ET.parse(fname)
all = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print('Dict count:', len(all))
for entry in all:
    if ( lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None ) : continue

    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist')
    genre = lookup(entry, 'Genre')
    album = lookup(entry, 'Album')


    if name is None or artist is None or album is None :
        continue

    print(name, artist, album, genre) #cambiar aber

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Artist (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( artist, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Artist WHERE name = ? ', (artist, ))
    artist_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
    genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Album (title, artist_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ? )''', ( album, artist_id ) )
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Album WHERE title = ? ', (album, ))
    album_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Track
        (title, album_id, genre_id)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)''',
        (name, album_id, genre_id) )

    conn.commit()
```

Comment: What output do you get for `print(name, artist, album, genre)`?

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in genre
```

means that your line

```py
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
```

didn't return any rows.

Did you *intend* to pass a tuple to the `SELECT`?

Comment: Passing a tuple is the standard way to supply arguments to be filled in for the `?` placeholders.  If there's only one `?`, then you pass a one-element tuple.

Comment: For the `insert`, sure. Even for the `select`?

Comment: I believe so.  SELECT and INSERT are equally vulnerable to injection attacks, so it would make sense to use parameterized statements for both.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Yes, you need to provide a iterable such as a tuple with one element if there is one bound variable, regardless of the SQL statement type.  Failure to do this causes a "Incorrect number of bindings supplied." error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lookup` function can return a string or None.  When it returns None, you will insert a NULL value.  In most SQL implementations, including SQLite, comparing anything to a NULL will result in a NULL, which is not true.  In other words, the query you immediately follow up with to find the id will not find a row, since no row will satisify the equation "genre = NULL".

Hence your failure. The call to `.fetchone()` returns None since there is no matching row, and you try to index into None, and it fails.

You'll need to special case the NULL value with something like this:

```
cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Genre (name)
        VALUES ( ? )''', ( genre, ) )
if genre is None:
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name IS NULL ')
else:
    cur.execute('SELECT id FROM Genre WHERE name = ? ', (genre, ))
genre_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem its that in SQL you cant use a "None" type value, so when your Python program parses the data from the xml file you get a "None" type value for the genre, you can fixed if you do the next:

if name is None or artist is None or album is None or genre is None :
continue